# Service in 2014; Billed in 2015 for Balance; Can I pay from 2015 FSA Funds?

Tags: fsa

My son went to the dentist on 9/22/2014. After the insurance paid a portion of the $125 fee, I was billed $53.60 on 2/25/2015. I submitted my FSA card to cover the balance on 3/12/2015.

When the administrator came to me for the documentation, I submitted the invoice from 2/22/2015. They refused this, saying that I paid for a 2014 service with 2015 funds. I called and noted that I only received the bill in 2015, but they still denied the receipt.

Are they right? I think they are wrong, but I cannot get them to accept the receipt.

Answer (score 1):

They are right. You can only use the FSA funds for the year in which you accrued the liability, regardless of when you paid it. See [the IRS publication 969](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000204184):

> Generally, distributions from a health FSA must be paid only to
>   reimburse you for qualified medical expenses you incurred during the
>   period of coverage.

Comment: +1 - this is also why you have a grace period to submit, usually till March 31 of the next year. His 2014 FSA would have covered this.